# Ansible 2.7 in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I'm looking for - and struggling to locate - any indication of when Ansible 2.7 will be released to the Azure Cloud Shell Bash environment. Currently Cloud Shell is at 2.6.3. Googling and DuckDuckGoing etc. and searching Microsoft's sites has not yielded much on this.

Comment: just update it?

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I did a pip install on ansible 2.7.0 and got a permission denied error after it downloaded and extracted. I assumed this was 'cause i was in cloud shell and MS were blocking it?

Comment: i think you can do a user scoped install or create a venv and install it there

Comment: ahhhh cool thanks for your help. will give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Ansible is showing 2.7.0 in Azure Cloud Shell. We make a regular release update every 2 weeks, coinciding with new releases of Azure CLI 2.0. We try to bundle OSS tooling updates as well - keep in touch with us at aka.ms/cloudshell/feedback for tooling you believe may be outdated.

Thanks for being a user!